# Excel VBA - How to cycle through a range and collect data in a row if reference cell contains value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA code to work within excel which will do the following:

I need to search through a column to find a date, once it is found I need 3 variables in that row to be copied over to another sheet in the same workbook. This is metocean data retrieved from the public domain, so dates are in order.

Below I've written a code which in my opinion SHOULD do the job, but for some reason only returns the first occurrence of the date which is used as input. I need it to copy the remaining days' code as well (ex. copy date corresponding to all the "January2"s in the data set).

```
Sub DataRetrieve()

Dim MDCount As Long
MDCount = 2

Dim OutputCount As Long
OutputCount = 5

Dim TimespanCount As Integer
TimespanCount = 0

Dim TimespanDAY As Range
Set TimespanDAY = Worksheets("TOOL").Cells((TimespanCount + 9), 5)

Dim HourCount As Integer
HourCount = 0

Dim Timespan As Range
Set Timespan = Worksheets("TOOL").Cells(6, 6)

Dim i As Integer
i = 0


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Do Until Worksheets("DATA").Cells(MDCount, 15) = "END"

    If TimespanDAY.Text = DayRead.Text Then
       Do Until HourCount = 24
            Worksheets("TEMP").Cells(OutputCount, 2) = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(MDCount, 7).Value
            Worksheets("TEMP").Cells(OutputCount, 3) = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(MDCount, 8).Value
            Worksheets("TEMP").Cells(OutputCount, 4) = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(MDCount, 9).Value

            MDCount = MDCount + 1
            OutputCount = OutputCount + 1
            HourCount = HourCount + 1
        Loop
    End If

    MDCount = MDCount + 1
    Set DayRead = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(MDCount, 4)
    Set TimespanDAY = Worksheets("TOOL").Cells((TimespanCount + 9), 5)
Loop

End Sub
```

Ideally, I'd like to expand this (once it works) to then restart the loop and go to the next corresponding date (ex. January3) do the exact same thing, and store in another column on the same sheet where the last data was stored.

I can explain more clearly if necessary. I appreciate any help! This is for a school project so time is of essence.

Andrew

Comment: Using a SQL statement might be an easier approach. Also you can use Range.Find to look for matches. I can take a look, where is the public data located?

Comment: Without sample data it will be difficult to figure out why your code is not working.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry guys, here's the link to the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18yrRuaP91RMKOpJGGe2VFlA8HTZgI_NE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm surprised your code works at all.  You never declare `DayRead`, and especially you don't `Set` it to anything prior to `If TimespanDAY.Text = DayRead.Text Then`

Comment: My apologies, seems like I lost some things when copying the code over here. DayRead is declared in memory as Range, and Set DayRead = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(MDCount, 4)